# Как сделать чтоб вместо обычного button была своя иконка

Tags: wordpress, button, wordpress-плагины

Всем привет. Есть готовая верстка. Но при создании темы на Wordpress столкнулся с тем, что не могу застилизовать до конца в сайдбаре виджит поиска (саму кнопку). Никак не подключается иконка. Кто с таким сталкивался или знает как можно решить эту задачку?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По скриншоту все становится очень понятно. Покажите что за иконка, как Вы ее подключаете, какие стили используете.

Comment: Иконку использую fa-search(https://fontawesome.com/v4/icon/search). Подключаю через сss, через свойство **background: url(' ');** :

Comment: #sidebar input.wp-block-search__input {
    padding-right: 40px;                                                                                                                              
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 150px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: block;
    padding: 18px 15px;
    margin: 0 20px 24px 0;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-width: 60px;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 24px;
    background: #D3D9D9;  
}

Comment: button.wp-block-search__button.wp-element-button {
    content: ' ';
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 21px;
    right: 48px;
    background-image:url('../assets/images/search-icon.png');
}

Comment: В самом файле sidebar.php код выглядит следующим образом:                                                         
 <aside id="sidebar">

    <?php dynamic_sidebar('left_sidebar') ?>

</aside>

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте код туда. Если иконка не отображается и в консоли 404 для файла иконки, то путь указан не верный.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. В пути ошибка была. Спасибо!